# Interface inheritance and Unity resolve

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am trying to resolve a object through it's **base** interface using Unity. If I have the following interfaces and classes:

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar : IFoo { }
class MyBar : IBar { }
```

and I want to inject `MyBar` into multiple classes like so:

```
class DoSomething
{
    public DoSomething(IFoo myBar) 
    { 
        // Execute a method from IFoo implementation 
    }
}

class DoSomethingElse
{
    public DoSomethingElse(IBar myBar) 
    { 
        // Execute a method from IBar **AND** IFoo implementation 
    }
}
```

If I register `MyBar` like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IBar, MyBar>();
```

Unity throws an error trying to resolve for `IFoo` (see the DoSomething constructor). But `IBar` inherits from `IFoo`?

I could register `MyBar` twice with the container like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, MyBar>();
container.RegisterType<IBar, MyBar>();
```

but it feels like I should not have to do this. I might be wrong here.

So my question is if Unity can resolve a class from its base interface?

Comment: If you want to use singleton registration for `MyBar` you should look for a way to tell the service container that in order to resolve `IFoo`, it can resolve `IBar` and cast down, otherwise each of the two interfaces will typically resolve to two distinct instances of the `MyBar` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically a DI-container tries to create instances of interfaces by some sort of mapping. So when you write

```
container.RegisterType<IBar, MyBar>();
```

the `container` knows, whenever I am requested to create some instance for `IBar` I resolve that call by instantiating `MyBar`.

However the container doesn´t know what to do what do if he is requested for an instance of `IFoo`, because not every `IFoo` is an `IBar`. So what should be returned when writing this:

```
container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
```

In your case only a single type is possible, `IBar` for which in turn also only a single type is possible. This however contradicts the purpose of interfaces, as in fact it´s allways bounded to one specific type, while it should work with *any* type implementing that interface.

That´s why you have to determine a mapping for both interfaces.

Comment: This makes 100% sense. Especially the part where you say: "_In your case only a single type is possible, IBar for which in turn also only a single type is possible. This however contradicts the purpose of interfaces, as in fact it´s allways bounded to one specific type, while it should work with any type implementing that interface._". My question is: Does this not also apply to IBar (IBar could be implemented by other classes)? Or should there always be a _single type_ or _class identifier_ interface?